# Stop postfix from sending non-delivery notifications when forwarded mail bounces

Tags: postfix

Some of my mail users are forwarding their mails to gmail for example. In some cases my Amavis lets some spam messages slip through. These mails are then bounced by gmail as they are spam. My postfix then tries to send non-delivery notifications to the (forged) from addresses, known as backscatter.

How can I stop postfix from sending non-delivery notification for mails that have bounced while forwarding them? Note I don't want to completely disable non-delivery notifications, only when forwarding mail.

Comment: That's a tough one, as postfix most likely has no idea who forwarded the message, is it done on your server (the forwarding.. procmail for example)?

Comment: @NickW postfix itself forwards the mails using virtual_alias_maps

Comment: Hmm, possibly you could add a header, that you could then check for on bounce

Comment: I have the same problem… in sendmail you can just add a `NAME-request` alias that gets the bounces instead of the sender